# Is there an open source NLP rules engine for python?

Tags: python, nlp

I am looking for an open source NLP rules engine, preferably one that will have a python interface.

The engine would accept defined rules such as 'send [x] a [y]' and would be able to map derivatives such as 'send Bob an email' and 'send Alice a sms' to it automatically (...will return the closest matching rule...).

Is there such a thing available?

(I have seen TextBlob mentioned in other answers, which seems like the building blocks for such an engine)

Comment: so why not use a regular expression 'sent (.*) to (.*)' to match?

Comment: @seagulf if he uses the regex you recommended he'll have to create many more of such. I guess what he needs is a library that interfaces with a rule based engine allowing him to create multiple grammar rules. On running a quick search [Pyke](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/) looks like something you might wanna take a closer look at.

Comment: checkout https://rasa.com/ it does that kind of things